# How to assign value for global variable within the parent function in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm trying to set a value of somewhat global variable in one function so that it would be accessible in another. Here's a stripped down code of mine.
I've tried all kind of ways how to define the variable but it keeps returning undefined.

```js
"use strict";
var MyTable = window.MyTable || {};

MyTable.LoadTable = function() {
  var myglobalvar = '';

  var first = function() {
    myglobalvar = "foo";
    // ...
    return deferred //returns promise
  }

  var second = function() {
    var localvar = MyTable.LoadTable.first() //returns deferred
    $.when.apply(null, localvar).done(function() {
      alert(myglobalvar) //I expect 'foo' but receive 'undefined'
    })
  }

  return {
    first: first,
    second: second
  }
}();
```

Could you kindly steer me to the right direction?

Comment: `second` doesn't `return` anything. Do you mean that it's alerting `undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index7</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        "use strict";
        var MyTable = window.MyTable || {};

        MyTable.LoadTable = function () {
            var myglobalvar = '';

            var first = function () {
                myglobalvar = "foo";
                // ...
                // Create a Deferred
                var defer = $.Deferred();
                return defer //returns promise
            };

            var second = function () {
                var localvar = first() //returns deferred
                $.when.apply(null, localvar).done(function () {
                    alert(myglobalvar) //I expect 'foo' but receive 'undefined'
                })
            }();

            return {
                first: first,
                second: second
            }
        }();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Mario84 , you can leave out the () after the functions and call your object with these lines:   var run = MyTable.LoadTable();
            run.second();

Comment: @Mario84 , you can keep your () after your function, put second() in the code, and remove the return statement.  JSFiddle is not working at the moment.